# Apollo + Angular mutation is not working with variables

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm having troubles creating mutations with variables. I can make it work including the values directly, like this:

```
export const orderCancellation = gql`
mutation{
  cancelOrder(input: {id: 2649,  cancellationReasonId: 1 } ) {
    order{
      id,
      isCancelled
    }
  }
}`;
```

But when try to use variables nothing works:

```
export const orderCancellation = gql`
mutation cancelOrder($id: ID!, $cancellationReasonId: ID!) {
  cancelOrder(input: {id: $id,  cancellationReasonId: $cancellationReasonId }) {
    order {
      id,
      isCancelled
    }
  }
}`;
```

The custom error message from our server:

```
Didn't find any result for  'CancelOrderPayload' with the arguments '{:input=>#<#<Class:0x00005608dca67e90>:0x00005608e10cd790 @context=#<Query::Context ...>, @ruby_style_hash={:id=>nil, :cancellation_reason_id=>nil}, @arguments=#<GraphQL::Execution::Interpreter::Arguments @keyword_arguments={:id=>nil, :cancellation_reason_id=>nil}>, @maybe_lazies=[]>}.
```

And this is how I call the mutation:

```
this.apollo.mutate({
  mutation: orderCancellation,
  variables: {id: orderId, cancellationReasonId: reasonId}
});
```

Does any one has clue on what i'm doing wrong? Maybe it's a server side problem?

**EDIT 1:** Here is the request payload with variables implementation (took from Network tab on Chrome DevTools):

```
operationName: "cancelOrder"
query: "mutation cancelOrder($id: ID!, $cancellationReasonId: ID!) {↵  cancelOrder(input: {id: $id, cancellationReasonId: $cancellationReasonId}) {↵    order {↵      id↵      isCancelled↵      __typename↵    }↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵"
variables: {id: "3045", cancellationReasonId: "1"}
```

**EDIT 2:** Already tried to declare the mutation like this:

```
export const orderCancellation = gql`
mutation cancelOrder($input: CancelOrderInput!) {
  cancelOrder(input: $input) {
    order {
      id,
      isCancelled
    }
  }
}`;

this.apollo.mutate({
     mutation: orderCancellation,
     variables: {input: {id: orderId, cancellationReasonId: reasonId}}
  });
```

Comment: bad /missing calues passed into variables ... console log them before mutation call ... check network request body if values passed properly

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added the request payload above. Is that enough?

Comment: integers vs strings?

Comment: @xadm sorry, i don't get it

Comment: `cancelOrder(input:....... {id: 2649,  cancellationReasonId: 1 }` ... `variables: .... {id: "3045", cancellationReasonId: "1"}` ... id 2649 vs id "3045"

Comment: I don't think that ID as string is a problem. We have a query that also uses variables and Apollo send the ID as string too:
`operationName: "getSingleOrder"
query: "query getSingleOrder($id: ID!) {↵  order(id: $id) {↵    id↵    ......."
variables: {id: "3045"}`

Comment: then it should work but usually don't .... try to pass $input at once

Comment: Already tried, but our server expects id and cancelReasonId to be explicit. Exemple on question EDIT2

Comment: should work ... server/api problem?... test in graphiql/playground  ... explore docs for this mutation specs, it will show you 'original' arg type ... if it's `input: CancelOrderInput!` then passing `input` is the safest way

Answer (score 0):

We figure it out what was the problem. Our server has declared the IDs for mutations as Integer!, instead of ID!. This is the cause of string ids was working with queries but not with mutations. Thanks for your effort!